# Java method boolean returning false when it's supposed to be true

Tags: java, object, methods, boolean

I am making this method in one class. I have doubled checked it and all and it should work accordingly. When I run an object in the main method using this method I always get a false return even though it's supposed to be true.

The print statements don't print so I can't check whether the values are being passed in properly and I also tried making the if statement return a true as well and it still returns false! It doing my head in as everything is logically correct.

Is there a rule I don't know about where a boolean method will automatically return false if somethings wrong?

```
public boolean addPartsDetails (String newDescription, double newCost) {

  System.out.println("is description empty?: " + newDescription);
  System.out.println("is cost negative?: " + newCost);

  if (newDescription.isEmpty() | newCost < 0) {   
     return false;
  }

  else {
     this.partsCost += cost;
     String newPart = String.format("\t - %s (%.2f) \n", description, cost);
     this.partsList = this.partsList.concat(newPart);
     return true;
  }
 }
```

In main method:

```
 boolean addBool = tempObj.addPartsDetails(partDes, partCost);

    if(addBool) {
       System.out.println("\nPart details recorded sucessfullyfor vehicle \"" +     tempObj.getRegNum() + "\"");
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("\nError - invalid part details supplied!");
    }
```

Comment: note: forgot to mention that partDes and partCost are already initialised in the main method

Comment: There's something else entirely wrong if your print statements don't get executed; those are unconditional. I don't think your program is getting to the quoted block at all.

Comment: Does it print "Error - invalid part details supplied!"?

Comment: Yes it prints  "Error - invalid part details supplied!" ! This is so frustrating ! and yeh what could be wrong if the print statements in the method are not printing?

Comment: Is the method overridden in any subclasses?

Comment: nope :( the correct type variables are getting passed in and everything! the method is public, and even if it wasn't i am accessing it from the object itself

Comment: Is tempObj a valid object?

Comment: and are you catching exceptions? Is partDes null?

Comment: I'm betting that the two are in different files and you didn't recompile the one that has `addPartsDetails`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use || instead of | here:

```
  if (newDescription.isEmpty() | newCost < 0) {
```

change it to

```
  if (newDescription.isEmpty() || newCost < 0) {
```

`|` is used for bitwise OR operation while `||` is used for conditional OR

Comment: The two operators aren't bitwise or logical in Java, just non-short-circuit and short-circuit, and since the OP said the print statements aren't being called, the problem is upstream in his calling code.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner [That applies when they're used on integral types, not on `boolean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2).